# Optimise database query that is converting bytes to megabytes and then ordering by desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a large table full of information on the different documents within my system.

Currently the filesize is stored in bytes, but I need to do a query where they are converted to megabytes, and then ordered on those megabytes.

The query is very slow thanks to the calculation that is going on and I was wondering if there is a way I could optimise it to run faster?

```
SELECT
   [DS_ID]
  ,[DS_Blob]
  ,[DS_Ext]
  ,[DS_FileSize] / 1048576 AS 'Size (in MB)'
  ,[DS_CV_ID]
  ,[DS_Filename]
  ,[DS_DataAccess]
FROM 
   [DS_DocumentStorage]
WHERE
   DS_FileSize > 1048576
ORDER BY 'Size (in MB)' DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options I can think of:

1. Add a column representing the size in Mb (with all the additional storage and keeping in-sync issues that brings).
2. Use a "computed column" with a function-based index:

```
    CREATE TABLE DS_DocumentStorage (
        ...
        DS_FileSizeMB AS [DS_FileSize] / 1048576
    );

    CREATE INDEX ix_DS_FileSizeMB ON DS_DocumentStorage(DS_FileSizeMB);
```

N.B. You should test the execution plan to see if this actually improves your situation.

Comment: The computed column worked really well - for anyone else looking for info, you can find it here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The greater than condition means that a table scan is needed. This means any index you have are rendered useless. The order by also screws up your execution plan.  if ordering the result outside sql server is not possible, then I suggest you put your query into an indexed view since you are pulling data from just 1 table anyway.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a link where you can learn about indexed views. An indexed view ensures your query execution plan performs an index seek instead of scans which will significantly improve the query execution plan and lessen the time it takes to pull data from the tables.

But then again, if you have a huge pool (tens of millions of rows or so) of data, then it will still take a few minutes for the execution to be finished.

Answer (score 0):

++ How does it matter if you just say "order by DS_FileSize desc" will be exactly same as "ORDER BY 'Size (in MB)' DESC"

Answer (score 0):

One thing I know which definitely work for you too. Either you add one column which is store calculated mb result and give non-clustered index like

Create index on that, so faster data will come.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD columnaname AS (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice * 1.35);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Address_PostalCode
ON Person.Address (PostalCode)
INCLUDE (AddressLine1, AddressLine2, City, StateProvinceID);
```

For alter table with computed column:-  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

For index create:-  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190806.aspx

For performance check of computed column :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189292.aspx

or

you can use [Index view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

for example,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer